# A* Path Finding Loops Forever

Tags: java, path-finding, path

For, hours, I've been following [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm).

```
public PathFinder(IntegralLocation loc, final int dest_x, final int dest_y) {
    boolean found = false;
    final List<Node> open = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Node> closed = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // 1. Add starting node to open list
    open.add(new Node(loc.getX(), loc.getY(), Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dest_x - loc.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(dest_y - loc.getY(), 2))));
    Node current = null;
    
    final int[] axs = new int[] { -1, 1 };
    final int[] ays = new int[] { -1, 1 };
    
    while(!open.isEmpty() && !found) {
        // 2a. Select current node
        for(Node n : open) {
            if(current == null) {
                current = n;
            } else {
                if(n.g < current.g) {
                    current = n;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // 2b. Switch it to the closed list
        open.remove(current);
        closed.add(current);
        
        // If this is the destination, we've found it
        if(current.x == dest_x && current.y == dest_y) {
            found = true;
        }
        
        // 2c. Handle surrounding squares
        for(final int ax : axs) {
            for(final int ay : ays) {
                final int x = current.x + ax;
                final int y = current.y + ay;
                if(!isNodeInList(x, y, closed)) {
                    Node n = getNodeFromList(x, y, open);
                    if(n == null) {
                        open.add(new Node(x, y, Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dest_x - x, 2) + Math.pow(dest_y - x, 2))));
                    } else {
                        if(n.g < current.g) {
                            n.setParent(current);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    canAccessDestination = found;
    System.out.println("This won't get printed.");

    // Save the actual path
    while (current != null) {
        nodes.add(new Point(current.x, current.y));
        current = current.getParent();
    }
    System.out.println(nodes.size());
    inverse_stage = nodes.size() - 1;
}
```

The code above is supposed to be an implementation of the A* path finding algorithm but it's an infinite loop.

The loop always ends up stuck at `n.setParent(current)`.

It is assumed, in this implementation that all nodes can be walked over.

I am sure that there is a tiny error somewhere but I can't quite find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm only looks at the diagonals:

```
final int[] axs = new int[] { -1, 1 };
final int[] ays = new int[] { -1, 1 };
...
for(final int ax : axs) {
    for(final int ay : ays) {
        final int x = current.x + ax;
        final int y = current.y + ay;
```

You need to also check the orthogonal tiles: (x+0, y+1), (x+1, y+0), (x+0, y-1), (x-1, y+0).

In addition, the loop variable `current` isn't reset. It should be reset at the top of the main loop so that you always grab a new node from the open list each time. This should happen around your comment:

```
// 2a. Select current node
```

Comment: Reset the `current` variable? Do you mean set it to `null` before the loop (as I thought that the loop below this comment reset it.)

Comment: `current` won't be null the during the second iteration of the loop, and therefore the 2a loop will be comparing each open node's G to the `current` G and since (I'm assuming) `current`'s G is smaller than all other G's (which is why you picked it), `current` will never change. Setting it to null forces the first branch of the loop to occur, grabbing the first node in the open list, then comparing all other open nodes to that instead.